# Increment or index value for list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, enumerate

Is there a handy way to get an autoincrement or index into a list comprehension? I’m trying to build a list of objects, each of which needs a unique identifier. So instead of this:

```
tags_list = ['art', 'science', 'lollipops']

class Tag:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

tags = []    
i = 1
for t in tags_list:
    tag = Tag(i, t)
    tags.append(tag)
    i += 1
```

…something like this:

```
tags = [Tag(i, t) for t in tags_list]
```

**^^^ how do I get `i`?**

I know about `enumerate()` but this gives me tuples right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tags = [Tag(i, t) for i,t in enumerate(tags_list, 1)]
```